# Random Number between 1 and 3

Tags: c, random

How can I generate a random number between 1 and 3?
With this function I get sometimes 0(i only wanna have 1,2 or 3):

```
ziehen=rand() % 3 + 1;
```

And why I have to add srand(0) in the main program?
I've added

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
```

to the Libaries. Is this enough or I need more?

Comment: _'or i need more?'_ Does it work?

Comment: Ah, the good old remainder technique. Please read http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/

Comment: Take a copy of the result of rand() and and use it in the computation ziehen.  Print its value when ziehen is zero.  It would be interesting to see which values give you zero.

Comment: The code you shown has no problems. If you get a `0` your problem is somewhere else, maybe the printing part of your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can never return 0. rand() always return a number between 0 and RAND_MAX.

The modulo operation return a value between 0 and 2. Adding 1 results in what you want.
No need for parenthesis. Modulo ranks above addition.

You don't have to add srand(0), but if you do it, you get always the same sequence of numbers. Read  the docs.

Comment: Technically, what you call “modulo operation” is called “remainder”. And it returns a value between -2 and 2 (hint).

Comment: But we have only values between 0 and RAND_MAX. How can this be negative?

Comment: Yes, I wonder how the OP managed it (and the OP says that stdlib.h is included, which should provide the prototype for `rand()`—a missing prototype was one of the ways I was thinking of)

Answer (score 2):

You must *never* use a modulus to reduce the periodicity of the output of `rand()`. Reason? It's because the low order bits of the standard linear congruential generator are less random than the higher order bits: the modulus discards the higher order bits.

The best thing to do is use `(3.0 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)) + 1.0;`. Implicitly cast this to `int` by assigning the output to an integral type.

`RAND_MAX` is defined by the C standard and its value is implementation dependent

Comment: Hm, and this will return `[0;3]`?

Comment: Yup, when implicitly cast to `(int)` it will return 1, 2, or 3. I've amended with a little more detail.

Comment: Might be little better, and often given as The Solution, but it isn't correct either, see http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html

Comment: @harold: I concur. But this is more correct. Ultimately it depends on the use requirement. I'd always shy away from `%` though as that almost always introduces bias unless, by coincidence, the periodicity of the generator is a multiple of the modulus.

Comment: @Bathsheba And your solution is floating-point? For uniform results? Are you sure the cure is not worse than the illness?

Comment: In general modulus does not discard higher order bits. Only if you take % 2 or % 4 , % 8, etc. Try to calculate % 3 and see how it depends on high order bits.